# How to synthesize this mixed pulse wave form from two different pulse trains?

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice

**Major Update:**

Throughout comments I noticed I was going wrong direction.
I think I need to synthesize the mixed pulse by using line and frame triggers generated by me. This way I can couple the frame and line triggers to galvo mirrors.

**Old question:**

So there is a trigger input to a camera which has mixed trigger input mode. I want to sync both the line trigger and the frame trigger with two galvo mirrors. But to do that I need to extract the frame pulse train and the line pulse train from the original mixed pulse train.

I tried to illustrate it below:
[image]

Is there a simple logic solution which I can also simulate in LTspice?

edit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just think through the details, which in my opinion we don't yet have. How would you discriminate between the two? We see a tiny context. You have more information. Please share with us.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add. The frame pulse has to be longer than the line
pulses.

Comment: Exact details are important. Not generic A>B.

Comment: Those are the only details. See my edit. I added the relevant page.

Comment: You're going to have to delay the output signal at least by the width of the line pulse (+ a bit extra) to determine whether a pulse is a frame pulse or a line pulse. Does that cause you any other problems?

Comment: I can set the periods of frame and line through registers. So you can just take them random as long as frame pulse is longer than frame maybe around 2048 times for instance.

Comment: @user16307 I guess we need to know what is in register 1211C and 12100?

Comment: A better way would be to count the pulses and reset the counter every time a frame pulse comes in. Counter = 0 outputs a frame pulse. Counter > 0 outputs a line pulse.

Comment: @jonk Okay I will add it. The document is not online thats why I add as image.

Comment: added those registers as well

Comment: I have to provide the mixed trigger pulse train to the camera. So how about generating two separate pulse train(one for frame and one for line) and OR them and send the output to the camera?

Comment: @user16307 Well, ***tbd*** isn't all that useful. I'll leave this to others.

Comment: @_Transistor and @jonk How about going the other way around. Instead of extracting we generate the frame and line trigger and synthesize the mixed one to be sent to camera? This way I can have access to frame and line pulse since we generate them separately. How could that be done in digital logic? I can update the question as well.

Comment: @user16307 That's a whole different question. And it may be much easier. But more specifications will be needs, obviously.

Comment: Yes if you generate the signal, it would be much easier to generate separate signals for your galvos rather than extracting them from the signal. You can do that with a bunch of PWM timers on a microcontroller, for example.

Comment: @jonk I changed the question I think I was going in wrong directions.

Comment: Can you give accurate timings on the waveform you want to generate? Width of frame pulse, width of line pulse, number of line pulses per frame, delay between frame pulse and line pulse, and line period

Comment: @bobflux line is 20kHz pulse train, and frame is 10Hz pulse train.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the process of answering what is now regarded as the **old question** when the goalposts were moved. So, given the information you originally provided, the best that can be achieved is this: -

[image]

- You can't generate a frame pulse until you know it isn't a line pulse and
- You can't generate a line pulse until you know it isn't a frame pulse.

Original timing diagram can't be met: -

[image]

**Major update to question**

> *Throughout comments I noticed I was going wrong direction. I think I
> need to synthesize the mixed pulse by using line and frame triggers
> generated by me.*

It looks like (or sounds like) you should merge the two individual lines together using an OR gate. It sounds as simple as that.

Comment: Sorry I changed the question. I really hope you can update your answer. It was wrong way of thinking. Instead of extracting we can generate the frame and line triggers and synthesize the mixed one to be sent to camera? This way I can have access to frame and line pulse since we generate them separately. How could that be done in digital logic? I updated the question before your answer.

Comment: But I kept the old verison anyway.

Comment: I answered the old question and you should respect that. Your new question just requires an OR gate to blend frame and line pulses to a combined signal.

Comment: @user16307 given the OR gate I suggested in the final line of my answer, can this question and answer session be closed with answer acceptance now?

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate this waveform, a simple option would be to use microcontroller PWM timers.

[image]

There are many ways to do it. One possibility is to have a timer run with a period of 20kHz to produce the line pulse, and put an interrupt on the timer that adjusts the pulse width when it is time to output a frame pulse. This can be used to generate more complex waveforms, for example adjust timer period to get different delays between line pulse and frame pulses, etc.

The same interrupt "knows" when a pulse is line or frame, so it can toggle a GPIO or use other timers to produce signals for your two different outputs when needed.

Using the micro's timer sync features, it should be possible to get perfect alignment between the edges of all signals.

Another option would be to use three timers as signal generators, one for the camera sync, and one for each mirror. Then store the required timer values in a RAM table, and use DMA to load them into the timers, synchronized with the timer overflow. Most microcontrollers that have DMA will allow it to be linked to the timers. If the DMA uses circular mode, this does not require an interrupt. This is essentially a DIY arbitrary waveform generator.

There are many other ways to do this, for example if you use an ESP32 you can use the [RMT](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/rmt.html) peripheral as an arbitrary waveform generator. If it has an I2S or SPI port, you can also build a bit pattern in RAM and transmit it.

Comment: What's wrong with using OR gate?

Comment: Do your galvo mirrors need exactly the same pulse width as your camera?

Comment: No they will remain same until the next line trigger

Comment: the relation  between  linetrigger and the DAC feeding the galvo(green) should be like this https://ibb.co/mGzK57h

Comment: OK, makes sense. If you use a micro with a DAC you can synchronize the DAC update with the timer that makes the line pulses. If you use an external DAC you can connect its LDAC input the line trigger. You can use an interrupt to update the DAC value, so the software loads the value, but the timing is done in hardware so it will be accurate.

Comment: I see and have a question. There are many tigger modes can be set. The camera has GPI pin for frame trigger and GPO pin for debug which is debugging for canera's line trigger. So I want to use that GPO for updating the DAC. But what worries me is that they mention is as debug output not external sync output.  Here about GPO from manual https://ibb.co/rGvFvFH Do you think i can use this output to sync the DAC?

Comment: I wouldn't count on it, if you generate frame and line sync you might as well use them directly... I'd use a third timer to synchronize the DAC though, because the mirror probably has a settling time, so you may want to start moving a little bit before the line pulse for example. Flexibility can't hurt...

Comment: I dont understand. If the mixed frame and line trigger wave form will be the GPIO. Then we already lost the camer line clock and our line trigger's sync.

Comment: I think I should send u the manual

Comment: Hmmm... I don't understand the last 2 comments